# Displaying xhtml content in a jsp page

Tags: jsp, xhtml

I have a JSP page that displays XHTML content. I have included the following lines at the top of my JSP page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<% response.setContentType("application/xhtml+xml"); %>
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
```

If I change the above line to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<% response.setContentType("application/xhtml+xml;charset=UTF-8"); %>
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
```

The page stops rendering and throws XML parsing error such as "semi colon expected somewhere in my javascript" or "processing instruction not found" etc etc.

Removing "charset=utf-8" from response.setContentType makes the page render. The only problem is that → shows up as a questin mark "?"

Answer (score 1):

> *The page stops rendering and throws XML parsing error such as "semi colon expected somewhere in my javascript" or "processing instruction not found" etc etc.*

That will happen if you declare XHTML as XML instead of "HTML with XML syntax". Indeed get rid of that XML declaration. If you can, I'd go a step further and just use HTML as real HTML, i.e. use `<!doctype html>` or any other `HTML strict` doctype. Also see http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/.

> ```
> <% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
> ```

First detail is that the `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` is way superfluous. At this stage it's already too late to set that. Second detail is that you're using scriptlets for that. I recommend not to do so. Use taglibs/EL where appropriate. If that's not possible, then the code logic actually belongs in a Java class, either directly or indirectly in a Servlet or Filter class.

> *Removing "charset=utf-8" from response.setContentType makes the page render. The only problem is that → shows up as a questin mark "?"*

The `response.setContentType(..)` is superfluous if you already set it as a `<meta>` tag in the HTML `<head>` which is imho much cleaner.

Finally you also need to set the response **character encoding** (that's different from setting the content type!) as follows:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

This by the way also implicitly creates a `<meta>` tag for the `content-type`. More background information and hints can be found [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Removed request.setCharacterEndocding, included <meta .... > under <head>, page renders but &rarr; still shows up as question mark.

Comment: <meta> with charset is ignored in XHTML by design. It's only for HTML (and HTML-pretending-to-be-XML in IE).

Answer (score 1):

You probably have code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> if (a && b) </script>
```

which is *forbidden* in XHTML mode, but *required* in `text/html` mode. You'll find explanation of this problem in [Sending XHTML as text/html Considered Harmful](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml).

And code like:

```
<a href="foo?bar&baz">
```

is not allowed in any version of HTML or XHTML. It must always be written as:

```
<a href="foo?bar&amp;baz">
```

Apparently you're not generating page using XML serializer (it wouldn't let you create invalid entities or improperly encoded characters), therefore I suggest that you use HTML 4 Strict or HTML5-as- `text/html` instead, which are more appropriate for hand-coded markup.